# Difference-in differences survival models

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, difference-in-difference, health-economics

I am in a setting where I'd like to estimate the average treatment effect on the treated (ATT) using a cox-proportional hazards model in a DID style setting. I'll adopt the setting of Mastrobuoni and Pinotti (2015) where the outcome of interest is recidivism as the example.

Because we can't estimate the ATT directly with the coxph, the corresponding hazard rate ratio of interest should be something like
$$ HRR = \frac{E[y_{it}(1)  |  t\geq t_0, D_i=1]} {E[y_{it}(0)  |  t\geq t_0, D_i=1]}$$
, where $t_0$ is the time of treatment, and $D_i = 1$ indicates that $i$ is in the treatment group. So this is the analog of the ATT, where we have the hazard rate of recidivism in the treated group after treatment over the counterfactual hazard rate in the treatment group had treatment not happened.

The following DID-style cox PH specification often gets used here, as in M&P2015:
$$h(t) = λ(t) exp ( \alpha_0 post + \alpha_1 treat + \beta post × treat)$$

So, we'd recover/estimate the $HRR$ using $exp(\hat{ \beta})$, right? But I don't think
$ E[exp(\hat{ \beta})]= HRR$ here as in the typical DID setting, because of the use of the coxPH.

Has anyone run across this question/ issue before? Do researchers who run this regression think that they recover $HRR$ or something else entirely? Thanks in advance!